# Generic getter and setter for value given table name, column name and id

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ado.net

Is there any way to write a generic getter and setter for value given table name, column name and id from entities generated from database in Entity Framework?

The generic getter would be something like

Pseudo Code:

```
public T GetValue<T>(string tableName, string columnName, int id)
{
   using(Entities context = new Entities())
   {
      return (from t in context.tableName
                where t has columnName && t.id == id
                select t.columnName).First();
   }
}

public void SetValue<T>(string tableName, string columnName, T value, int id)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely possible, but you'll have to get into at least constructing expressions by hand, if not also reflection. Your way also loses some type (and typo!) safety which is one of the big advantages of proper ORM.

While it's possible to get around this by using more expressions and generics, the question remains - why do you want to do this? To be honest, these functions do not look like something I'd imagine using in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much for the respond. I still can't get the function work yet. I have multiple tables; one of these tables has table names and the name of the column name of the primary keys of the other tables and as more tables will be added to the database. My goal is to write the generic getter and setter given table names, column names and id as strings.

Comment: I am very new to ADO.Net so please forgive me for my lack of experience. I also would like to know if my entity data model can update itself by creating entities as new tables are added to the schema. Thank you very much.